# How to make JTree with checknode in netbeans GUI?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtree

I just drag the JTree from Netbeans GUI. I want all its node should contain checkbox for selecting more than one node. How to convert JTree with checkbox? should i change any property for that?[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add checkbox to JTree node to manage multiselection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870908/how-to-add-checkbox-to-jtree-node-to-manage-multiselection)

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2105371/2587435)

Comment: shold i write coding for that? because i just drag in from swing palette.. Should i change any property for JTree to convert it with checkbox?